# Choosing which values to keep when merging rasters

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, overlay

I figured this would be a simple problem but I cannot seem to find the solution. I have two rasters as DEMs (digital elevation models). One is of the entire area of interest and represents the original topography. The other is of a smaller area within the area of interest, and represents the proposed landscape changes. I want to merge these two rasters. The final result would be a raster for the entire area of interest, with the values in the proposed area adjusted to match the proposed raster. I.e. it would use the proposed values in the areas they exist and the original values everywhere else.

I see this as burning the new raster into the existing raster, but perhaps this isn't the right terminology.

Is there a way to do this in QGIS or ArcGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. When you specify multiple software stacks, you're effectively asking multiple Quesions, so the question is at risk to be closed for lack of *focus*. Additionally, "Is it possible" questions are likely to result in "Yes" answers, when what you really want is "*How* is it possible." Please [Edit] the question to improve the focus.

Answer (score 2):

You can use gdalwarp https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#gdalwarp. The same tool is available through the QGIS menu Raster - Projections - Warp but unfortunately it cannot be used by having an existing image as a target. QGIS creates the gdalwarp command with option `-of GTiff` and that leads to a GDAL error:

```
ERROR 1: Output dataset target.tif exists,
but some command line options were provided indicating a new dataset
should be created.  Please delete existing dataset and run again.
```

The gdalwarp command that QGIS creates is not editable and user cannot remove the `-of` parameter that makes the tool to create a new file. Otherwise existing image can be used as a target as documented.

> The destination file name.
>
> Mosaicing into an existing output file is supported if the output file
> already exists. The spatial extent of the existing file will not be
> modified to accommodate new data, so you may have to remove it in that
> case, or use the -overwrite option.

Fortunately you do not need QGIS but you can run gdalwarp from the GDAL command line. Basic usage is:

```
gdalwarp change_dem.tif original_dem.tif
```